# Generate each possible string combination of char and numbers

Tags: combinations

i want to generate each possible string (all 36^n strings) of numbers and chars of the length n.

Input:

```
n = 4
Numbers 0-9
Chars a-z
```

Output:

```
0000
0001
0002
...
0dn1
0dn2
...
zzzz
```

Comment: you need to be more specific... which programming language, what did you try so far?

Comment: What are you proposing to do with them once you have them? It'd take a lot of paper to print them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An invaluable resource from Princeton and Robert Sedgewick.

Covers recursive permutations and combinations.

Two implementations in Java to get all combinations of a given String.

http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Combinations.java.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive solution to generate combinations.
Generate combinations for n = 4 is generating combinations for n = 3 and adding all possibles values.

Here an example in Java:

```
for (char ch = '0' ; ch <= '9' ; ch ++) {
    generateCombinations(size - 1, combination + ch);
}
```